# How to fix the text cursor position in an html textarea with unicode-bidi: plaintext with a RTL language?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, unicode, bidi

We've been using textareas with the css setting `unicode-bidi: plaintext` this handled mixing left to right and right to left languages beautifully until about 2 months ago with the new release of chrome.  The text positioning still works properly, but from chrome 86 and on (I think - I don't remember which version broke this) the cursor started jumping to the beginning of the line after a space with RTL languages. Take a look the recording here...
[image: cursor jumps to beginning of the line in RTL languages]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YursB.gif

In chromium edge the cursor positioning still works, but not everyone wants to use edge.
Anyone know how to fix the cursor jump after a space for RTL languages?

Comment: I have the same problem. Just setting `dir=auto` and not explicitly setting `unicode-bidi` works perfectly in Firefox. In Chrome I have to set `unicode-bidi: embed` to somewhat fix this. But that then breaks in Firefox. `unicode-bidi` needs to be `plaintext`.